# How do you enable Feature Gates in K8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to enable a few Feature Gates on my bare-metal K8s cluster(v1.13). I've tried using the kubelet flag `--config` to enable them, as `kubelet --feature-gates <feature gate>` throws an error saying that the feature has been deprecated.

I've created a .yml file with the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
feature-gates:
    VolumeSnapshotDataSource=true
```

and after running: "kubelet --config , I got the following error:

```
I0119 21:59:52.987945   29087 server.go:417] Version: v1.14.2
I0119 21:59:52.988165   29087 plugins.go:103] No cloud provider specified.
W0119 21:59:52.988188   29087 server.go:556] standalone mode, no API client
F0119 21:59:52.988203   29087 server.go:265] failed to run Kubelet: no client provided, cannot use webhook authentication
```

Does anyone know what could be happening and how to fix this problem?

Comment: The yaml should be `    VolumeSnapshotDataSource: true` and you should replace or add the config/command line to your running `kubelet` instances on the cluster rather than running it interactively

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't apply `--feature-gates` to the kubelet. You do it to the `API-server`. Depending on how have you installed kubernetes on bare metal, you would need to either stop `API-server`, edit the command you start it with and add the following parameter:

```
--feature-gates=VolumeSnapshotDataSource=true
```

Or, if it is in a pod, find the manifest, edit it and re-deploy it (it should happen automatically, once you finish editing). It should look like this:

```
...
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=10.132.0.48
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --feature-gates=VolumeSnapshotDataSource=true
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.16.4
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 10.132.0.48
        path: /healthz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
...
```

Comment: Note - for kubeadm based system, you can edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml an delete the kube-apiserver pod to restart it

Comment: yep. that's the way when the `api-server` runs on a pod.

Comment: Not sure to understand, if feature gates can't be applied to `kubelet`, why kops doc refer also to kubelet? https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cluster_spec.md#feature-gates

Answer (score 0):

It(VolumeSnapshotDataSource) is a default feature in 1.17 beta releases. It needs to be enabled in API server if the kubernetes version is less than 1.17.