# Expose both TCP and UDP from the same ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

In kubernetes, I have the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: tcp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5555
      targetPort: 5555    
    - name: udp
      protocol: UDP
      port: 5556
      targetPort: 5556
  selector:
    tt: test
```

Which exposes two ports, 5555 for TCP and 5556 for UDP. How can expose these ports externally using the same ingress? I tried using nginx to do something like the following but it doesn't work. It complains that mixed ports are not supported.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  5555: "default/test-service:5555"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: udp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  5556: "default/test-service:5556"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: tcp
      port: 5555
      targetPort: 5555
      protocol: TCP
    - name: udp
      port: 5556
      targetPort: 5556
      protocol: UDP
  args:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The support for mixed TCP/UDP protocols depends on the cloud provider. Which cloud provider are you using ?

Comment: @Malgorzata digital ocean

Answer (score 2):

Most cloud providers do not support UDP load-balancing or mix protocols and might have cloud-specific methods to bypass this issue.

> The DigitalOcean CPI does not support mixed protocols in the Service
> definition, it accepts TCP only for load balancer Services. It is
> possible to ask for HTTP(S) and HTTP2 ports with Service annotations.
>
> Summary: The DO CPI is the current bottleneck with its TCP-only limitation. As long as it is there the implementation of this feature
> will have no effect on the DO bills.

See more: [do-mixed-protocols](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/1438/files).

A simple solution that may solve your problem is to create a reverse
proxy system on a standalone server - using Nginx and route UDP and
TCP traffic directly to your Kubernetes service.

Follow these two steps:

**1.**  Create a NodePort service application

**2.**  Create a small server instance and run Nginx with LB config on it

Use [**NodePort**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)  type of service which will expose your application on your cluster nodes, and makes them accessible through your node IP on a static port. This type supports multi-protocol services. Read more about services [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5555
    targetPort: 5555
    nodePort: 30010    
  - name: udp
    protocol: UDP
    port: 5556
    targetPort: 5556
    nodePort: 30011
  selector:
    tt: test
```

For example this service exposes `test` pods’ port 5555 through `nodeIP:30010` with the TCP protocol and port 5556 through `nodeIP:30011` with UDP. Please adjust ports according to your needs, this is just an example.

Then create a small server instance and run `Nginx` with LB config.

For this step, you can get a small server from any cloud provider.
Once you have the server,  `ssh`  inside and run the following to install Nginx:

```
$ sudo yum install nginx
```

In the next step, you will need your node IP addresses, which you can get by running:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide.
```

**Note:**  If you have private cluster without external access to your nodes, you will have to set up a point of entry for this use ( for example NAT gateway).

Then you have to add the following to your `nginx.conf` (run command `$ sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
worker_processes 1;  
events {  
    worker_connections  1024;  
}  
stream {  
  upstream tcp_backend {  
    server <node ip 1>:30010;  
    server <node ip 2>:30010;  
    server <node ip 3>:30010;  
         ...  
  }  
  upstream udp_backend {  
    server <node ip 1>:30011;  
    server <node ip 2>:30011;  
    server <node ip 3>:30011;  
         ...  
  }  
  server {  
      listen 5555;  
      proxy_pass tcp_backend;  
      proxy_timeout 1s; }  
  server {  
      listen 5556 udp;  
      proxy_pass udp_backend;  
      proxy_timeout 1s;  
  }  
}
```

Now you can start your Nginx server using command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

If you have already started you Nginx server before applying changes to your config file, you have to restart it - execute commands below:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn    # Get the PID of nginx.conf program  
$ sudo kill -2 <PID of nginx.conf>  
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

And now you have UDP/TCP LoadBalancer which you can access through  `<server IP>:<nodePort>`.

See more: [tcp-udp-loadbalancer](https://medium.com/asl19-developers/build-your-own-cloud-agnostic-tcp-udp-loadbalancer-for-your-kubernetes-apps-3959335f4ec3).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I know, using NodePort in production is not recommended, that's why I need to use LB.

Comment: You should have specified this in your post - please consider creating extra one post specifying that. You can give me a link and I could take a look. Also consider to upvote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable [feature gates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) `MixedProtocolLBService`. For instructions on how to enable function gates, see below.

- [How do you enable Feature Gates in K8s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814862/how-do-you-enable-feature-gates-in-k8s)

Restart (delete and re-create) the Ingress controller after enabling it for the settings to take effect.

`MixedProtocolLBService` is a beta feature since Kubernetes 1.20. Whether it becomes stable or depprecated remains to be seen.